# Return same elements of two sets in Clojure

Tags: collections, clojure, set

I have two sets:

`#{1 2 3}` and `#{7 8 3}`

and I'd like to create a function that returns just the shared values of each set, 3.

I can't use intersection; it doesn't work with my current version of clojure.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that clojure.set/intersection does not work with the version of Clojure this project is using?

Answer (score 5):

The [`clojure.set/intersection`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.set/intersection) function has been there for as long as I can remember, are you sure you're using it correctly? this should definitely work:

```
(require '[clojure.set])
(clojure.set/intersection #{1 2 3} #{7 8 3})
=> #{3}
```

Or maybe it's time to update to a more recent version of Clojure...

Comment: I wasn't requiring clojure.set. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why `clojure.set/intersection` isn't available to you, but you can define your own.

A simple implementation is

```
(defn intersection [x y]
  (into #{} (filter (partial contains? x) y)))
```

giving

```
(intersection #{1 2 3} #{7 8 3})
;#{3}
```

You can find a fuller and faster version [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.set/intersection#source).